# How do I differentiate between clicking a submit button and hitting enter in an input to submit a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Specifically, I do NOT want to use the already-recommended method of `event.preventDefault()` when the enter key is pressed, because that breaks functionality for datalists in at least Internet Explorer.

I've tried something along the lines of

```
$("#form").submit(function(event){
    console.log(event);
    return false; // Allows me to read the console before the form submits!
});
```

To compare the differences between the events (clicking the submit button vs hitting the enter key), and there doesn't seem to be anything obvious. I would have expected the latter to have an `event.keyCode`, but that's not the case.

A long-winded workaround that I can think of seems to be to remove my submit button, and replace it with a regular button whose click is bound to submitting the form. But that way, I'll have to capture the enter key presses in inputs and deal with submitting the form from scratch. Ugly, but doable. Again, I do **NOT** want to apply any `preventDefault()`s if I can help it.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between pressing enter and clicking the submit button? Knowing this may help us come up with a solution.

Comment: @KevinB, I have a form where I do not want the enter key to submit the form.* (Yes, I understand there is considerable following of people who don't want the native operations of a form to be interrupted like this). The usual recommendation is to simply apply event.preventDefault() when the keycode (or event.which) is 13. So my code right now does preventDefault(), but that means the enter key can't be used to select an item from a datalist in Internet Explorer.

*In certain inputs, hitting enter key is a shortcut for other operations (like when input is "14-17", adds numbered rows to a table)

Comment: I would suggest using the click event on the submit button and removing the form tag, assuming you're submitting the form using ajax. That will cause pressing enter to no longer cause a submit without preventing the default behavior. If not using ajax, you could still have a hidden form that you simply move your inputs to before calling it's submit method.

Comment: (I'm using Perl CGI) Would it be better form (no pun intended) to remove the form, or change the button[type=submit] to button[type=button] ?

Comment: It would be less complex to just do what you were already doing in your question i'd think.

Comment: Brilliant! Sometimes we know that the path we're taking will certainly yield a solution, but we don't know if there's an easier yet-unknown path. Thank you.

Comment: My solution only really works if you were submitting with ajax, otherwise you then have to deal with moving inputs around which is way more work than what you were already doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of a hacky solution, but you can tie the event handler to a `click` on the `submit` button, instead of a `submit` of the `#form`.  Then you can check if there were non-zero coordinates associated with the event.  If so, the `submit` button was clicked, if not, the enter key was pressed.  e.g.

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(event){
    if (event.screenX === 0) alert("You hit the enter key!");
    else alert("You clicked the submit button!");

    return false; // Allows me to read the console before the form submits!
});
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/52wrx1dL/)

Comment: This is interesting! I hadn't considered dealing with the condition inside the click event... honestly because I didn't know the click event registers when enter is hit within another input (I never technically clicked the button!). This has no condition for when the spacebar is hit and the button is selected, but that's easy to add.

Comment: Double comment: This is not fool-proof, is it? What if someone happens to click at exactly (0,Y)?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That's why I said it was kind of hacky.  In theory, even if you check against `event.screenX === 0` AND `event.screenY === 0`, in theory, the submit button could be placed at exactly (0, 0)--(screenX, screenY) and the event could happen at exactly that location when the submit button is pressed.  So you'd just have to make sure the button is never at (0, 0)

Comment: I feel like as long as the whole body has padding, it would be more secure to use pageX/Y. The window can easily be moved halfway off-screen, but the content does not budge so willingly.

Comment: Well yes. The best solution would be to check `if (event.screenX === 0 && event.screenY === 0 && event.pageX === 0 && event.pageY === 0 && event.offsetX === 0 && event.offsetY === 0 && event.clientX === 0 && event.clientY === 0)`.  This is obviously overkill. I'd recommend using however much of that you deem prudent.

Comment: Note that if a user tabs to a submit button, and then presses the space or enter key, the mouse coords will also be 0. That may or may not be desirable - just an FYI.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `mousedown` event instead, which will not be triggered by pressing the enter key

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('mousedown', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The click event contains attribute `detail` that contains the click count. If `detail` is `0`, no button was clicked, so the form must have been submitted using the keyboard.

[MDN: Event detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail)

Answer (score 1):

I have a much simpler answer, which avoids all that complication.  And when you hear it you'll think "why didn't I think of that!!".  You have 2 forms.  All your fields go in the first form, and just the Submit button in the second.  The onsubmit of the first just says "return false;", and the onsubmit of the second calls a function which also returns false.  But the function called by the second form manually submits the form with all the fields.  Hence only the submit button submits the first form, not any return key press of any of its input fields.  And of course the user won't know any difference! (except that  they are saved from accidentally submitting a form before they're ready)

Comment: Not the better written answer, but this is the best solution. The accepted answer, and the answer with 2 votes are both hacks that are a disruption to browser standards and accessibility. Using multiple forms with multiple submit buttons is clean and easy. Submit buttons that should be invisible to sighted users can be styled off-screen with an absolute position, this will allow for assistive technology to still 'click' the button, and it will allow sighted/keyboard users to press 'enter'. There is nothing that prevents using JS to manually tie together multiple submit handlers in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to chime in so late, but I am working through similar issues. The above answers, excepting the one from @Clive are hacky and go against default browser behavior. While these kinds of hacks may work on some browsers, and for some users, there is a good chance they disrupt assistive technology like screenreaders. Spec exists for more than the visual representation of the DOM.

I am gathering that the question is here:

> Specifically, I do NOT want to use the already-recommended method of
>   event.preventDefault() when the enter key is pressed... ... To compare
>   the differences between the events (clicking the submit button vs
>   hitting the enter key), and there doesn't seem to be anything
>   obvious...

Consider this:

```
<form>
  <input />
  <!-- This is best practice for accessibly hiding DOM elements for sighted users -->
  <button
    type="submit" 
    style="position:absolute;display:block;left:-10000px;width:1;height:1;overflow:hidden;" 
    onClick="function(evt) {
      console.log('User pressed enter to submit form, or focused to this off-screen button potentially using a screenreader.', evt.target);
    }">
      this is the form submission button
  </button>
  <!-- You could include a hidden label here to explain why there are two submit buttons to screenreader users, there also may be an aria property -->
  <button
    type="button"
    onClick="function(evt) {
      console.log('user clicked custom submit button to submit form', evt.target);
    }">
      this is the visible submit button
  </button>
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bevr1337/L3v864ob/)

mousedown is a dangerous event to use to trigger non-style actions. Users who accidentally click a button can no longer change their mind. Traditionally, you can select or focus any element on a web page with the option to drag away or refocus to prevent a button action or link navigation. onclick is a nice generic event for many browsers, there is less risk here of weird behavior between different input devices.

As noted in many comments on the accepted solution (including the author), relying on coordinates to determine the origin of an event is not reliable. There is likely always one more way to break the expected behavior no matter how many sanity checks are included. At that point, you've engineered a very complicated solution to a simple problem.

tl;dr use two buttons, hide the "submit" button off-screen.

Good luck!